# How to know people get promoted on Azure AD User Object

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to get the information if a user in Azure AD get promoted. Information i got so far from this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

**There is a JobTitle property, but i don't see property like: JobTitleHistory, or JobTitleChangeDate**

Is there a workaround to get the promotion information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such field like `JobTitleHistory`, or `JobTitleChangeDate`.
There is a workaround you can get to know what changes are made to user profile using delta query.

I tested in my environment by changing the **JobTittle=Null** to **JobTittle=Software Engineer** :

[image]

> Delta Query: The purpose of delta query is to retrieve all the
> changes.

Use the below URL to generate the `@odata.nextLink`

```
 URL:  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta/?$filter=id eq‘Object ID’
```

[image]

Use `@odata.nextLink` link to get the changes to for particular user. Use Key Value prefer:return=minimal in Request Header to get only the updated attribute.

[image]
[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview

Comment: Forgot to say thanks and mark this as the answer, cheers!